# Can data be changed during multi-select request?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a request with multiple SELECT from one table (FileInstance) and these SELECTs use MAX function. 
Is it any gaurantee that during this INSERT statement `SELECT MAX(Sequence) FROM FileInstance` will give the same result?
Is it possible that a record can be added between these SELECTs and I will catch different values?

```
INSERT INTO
    FileInstance (Data, Size, FileID, ChangesetID)
VALUES
(
    (SELECT Data FROM FileInstance WHERE FileID=%1 AND Sequence=(SELECT MAX(Sequence) FROM FileInstance WHERE FileID=%1)),
    (SELECT Size FROM FileInstance WHERE FileID=%1 AND Sequence=(SELECT MAX(Sequence) FROM FileInstance WHERE FileID=%1)),
    %1,
    NULL
);
```

Of cource, I think that two calls SELECT MAX(Sequence) FROM FileInstance WHERE FileID=%1 will be converted to one call, but I just want to be sure.

I use postgresql 9.2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the statement sees a consistent view of the database while it's running. So both sub-selects will return the same value.

**Edit:** I think a note on concurrent inserts might be needed as well. If some other transaction inserts a higher sequence number while your statement is running that can result in an error if you have a unique index on the sequence.

If the sequence column does not need to be gap-free, using a **real** sequence is probably the better solution.

If you want to avoid problems with concurrent transactions, you probably want to change the isolation level to "serializable" before running the insert.

---

Your statement is very inefficient however. This can be simplified to:

```
INSERT INTO FileInstance 
  (Data, Size, FileID, ChangesetID)
SELECT Data, Size, %1, NULL
FROM FileInstance 
WHERE FileID=%1 
AND Sequence = (SELECT MAX(Sequence) 
                FROM FileInstance 
                WHERE FileID=%1);
```

The select statement might be even faster by removing the sub-select and replacing it with a window function:

```
INSERT INTO FileInstance 
  (Data, Size, FileID, ChangesetID)
select Data, Size, fileID, NULL
from (
  select data, 
         size,
         fileid,
         max(sequence) over (partition by fileId) as max_seq,
         sequence
  from fileinstance
  where fileID = %1
) t
where sequence = max_seq;
```

Comment: Thank you, and for optimisation too.

Comment: @Serhiy: see my edit regarding problems with concurrent transactions.

Comment: In my case concurent insert is not possible, I've got a guard in other table as unique record.